# can we do push notification in iphone using phonegap framework?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, cordova

I need basic idea about how to implement push notification using phonegap framework.

Comment: Please mark as answer if the proposed answer satisfies your need.

Comment: He did a 'hit and run' :) blergh

Answer (score 24):

Yes we can:
The latest version of that beta offered developers a very exciting new feature just this morning - push notification of new messages. That means apps will be able to send SMS style messages when something important occurs

Taken from this website:

> http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/introduction-to-phonegap-framework-t1686.html

To have complete documentation for PhoneGap, go to http://wiki.phonegap.com

And also, we have several tools with PhoneGap, which are:-

> (a) PhoneGap simulator(cross-platform)
>
> (b) XUI :- JavaScript framework for mobile device browsers
>
> (c) Lawnchair:- It is a clent-side JSON store
>
> **(d) Easy APNS :- Push notifications using Php & MySQL**
>
> (e) Sony WebSDK:- To make mobile applications to work on multiple devices
>
> (f) Urban Airship :-It offers services like: Push notifications, Air Mail, In-App purchase.

So as you can see PhoneGap does offer this solution. Just visit the documentation and it will help you.

If this answer was helpful please mark this post as answered.
If you need any more help do let me know.

Pk

Comment: Another service that offers phonegap push notifications, and for free: - PushApps : http://www.pushapps.mobi