# Receiving push notification on PhoneGap for iOS

Tags: iphone, cordova, push, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hello everybody 
I would like to receive Apple push notifications through my PhoneGap container. Does anybody now if it has already been implemented?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check this link.  It worked for me 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884468/receiving-push-notification-on-phonegap-for-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.

See [Urban Airships documentation for Phonegap iOS plugin](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client:+PhoneGap)

Comment: so UA have created a plug-in for PhoneGap. Do you think I can use it freely in my app and connect it to any other Push Notification service that is not Urban Airship?

Comment: @Claus: I have not used it myself. I stumbled upon it while I was looking for the same functionality in Titanium Appcelerator.

Comment: Ok I will try to figure it out.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

*Yes we can*

check these links:

[can we do push notification in iphone using phonegap fremwork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811251/can-we-do-push-notification-in-iphone-using-phonegap-fremwork/3811346#3811346)

[How to implement UA push notifications with PhoneGap](http://help.urbanairship.com/kb/push-notifications/how-to-implement-ua-push-notifications-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty good - https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin 
Here is a tutorial using the above - http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

Comment: This is the one I used recently & works like a charm. Gets the job done & no need to send Push notifications via a third-party service like pushwoosh or others. Loved it as I already had my push notification server in PHP

Answer (score 1):

There are many services that can help you for doing this:

-[Urban airship](http://urbanairship.com/)

-[Puship](http://www.puship.com/)

-Pushwoosh

-Parse

and some are free! I'm using puship and I'm very satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: Pushwoosh has the most diverse selection of platforms in their guides, including PhoneGap plugins for four basic platforms, and the easiest integration so far!

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/