# Is it Possible to have a push notification in phonegap without using any third party library?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

i am new to phonegap application development,i want to use push notification in my phone gap application i got that it is possible to use push notification in phonegap application using some third party libraray from here i got that.[Receiving push notification on PhoneGap for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884468/receiving-push-notification-on-phonegap-for-ios)

but my query is that i want to know is it posible to use push notification in phonegap application without using third party library?
i googled for it but could not get solution
i hope some one will be helpful to this issue 
thanks in advance
Aamirkhan i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Android (the cross platform issue might be why people swing towards third party solutions...), but on iOS all you need is a plugin and your own APN server.

Plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/PushNotification

For the server, one way might be to set it up on a free-ish service like Heroku using one of these resources:

1. https://github.com/esilverberg/Heroku-APNS
2. http://orderoo.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/apple-push-notifications-on-heroku-using-node-js-8/

etc

Comment: is it possible we can use push notification in phonegap without any third party api?

Comment: If you mean without using any plugins or any hacking of the native code in the app, then no.