# How can PhoneGap or Titanium apps programmatically invoke JavaScript on a HTML5 page?

Tags: iphone, html, ios4, jquery-mobile, cordova

Assume we have a HTML5 web page embedded within a PhoneGap or Titanium app.

Can the app invoke JavaScript functions found within the HTML5 web page?

Specifically: after the app receives an Apple push notification, how can the app invoke one of the JS functions on the web page?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you asking how to do it in PhoneGap? or are you asking how PhoneGap does it?

How PhoneGap does it:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

`UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method.

Edit: how to respond to push notifications in phonegap: [can we do push notification in iphone using phonegap framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811251/can-we-do-push-notification-in-iphone-using-phonegap-fremwork)

Comment: The former ... thanks! We execute this method from within PhoneGap?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is for the latter. Never used phonegap.